# how to shift a string to right and reverse it in python?

Tags: python

Shift word to right and then reverse it.

You should take a word shift to right and reverse it then return as follows:

```
>>> shift_reverse('Introduction to Computer Programming')
gnimmargorP noitcudortnI ot retupmoC
```

I tried using this method to find the above answer but it doesnt seem to work
Please help :(

```
s= "I Me You"
def shift_reverse(s):
    l= s.split()
    new_str= ' '.join(l[-1:] + l[:-1])
    new_str = new_str[::-1]
    return (new_str)

print (shift_reverse(s))
```

but the print i get is

```
[evaluate untitled-3.py]
eM I uoY
```

Comment: Either reverse-split-reorder-join, or split-reorder-reverse-join. You are doing neither.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse each of the re-ordered list:

```
reordered = l[-1:] + l[:-1]
new_str = ' '.join(word[::-1] for word in reordered)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join a generator expression that generates reversed words in the rotated split list:

```
>>> s = 'Introduction to Computer Programming'
>>> ' '.join(w[::-1] for w in (lambda l: l[-1:] + l[:-1])(s.split()))
'gnimmargorP noitcudortnI ot retupmoC'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step with the functions:

Create `shift` function to move last word to beginning:

```
def shift(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    return ' '.join([words[-1]] + words[:-1])
```

Create `reverse` function to reverse all words in a sentence (uses [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)):

```
def reverse(sentence):
    return ' '.join([word[::-1] for word in sentence.split()])
```

Create `shift_reverse` to reverse all words and then `shift` the last on to the start:

```
def shift_reverse(sentence):
    return shift(reverse(sentence))
```

Result:

```
shift_reverse('Introduction to Computer Programming')
```

Output:

```
'gnimmargorP noitcudortnI ot retupmoC'
```

Answer (score 0):

In `new_str = new_str[::1]`, you're reversing the entire string, character per character.

```
ghi abc def
fed cba ihg
```

You have to reverse each word in the `list` of words.

```
def shift_reverse(string):
    words = string.split()
    shifted_words = [words[-1]] + words[:-1]
    return ' '.join([word[::-1] for word in shifted_words])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def shift_reverse(s):
    rev = ["".join(reversed(word)) for word in s.split(" ")]
    return "{} {}".format(rev.pop(), " ".join(rev))
```

reverse all the strings, pop the last off the list of reversed words and join the remainder.

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can shift the string over, the reverse each item:

```
>>> phrase = 'Introduction to Computer Programming'
>>> new = ' '.join([word[::-1] for word in [phrase.split()[-1]]+phrase.split()[:-1]])
>>> print new
gnimmargorP noitcudortnI ot retupmoC
>>>
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work for you

```
s= "Introduction to Computer Programming"
def shift_reverse(s):
    l= s.split()
    l = [l.pop()]+ l
    return ' '.join(i[::-1] for i in l)

print (shift_reverse(s))
```

output:

```
   gnimmargorP noitcudortnI ot retupmoC
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It has the output the OP asked for